# apply ifelse on a vector with two logical values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a vector of values, and I want to decide what elements of this vector are in some interval and what elements aren't.

So I did the following:

```
vec <- ifelse( 1<va2<3, 1, 0);
```

but i am getting an error saying : unexpected '<' in vec 
so I tried the following:

```
vec <- ifelse( 1<va2 && va2<3, 1, 0);
```

but it's giving me only the first value.

so how to do to get the ifelse working with two logical values, or is there any alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `&` not `&&` for elementwise comparisons, it is the one you should use when performing logical comparisons over a vector of elements.

```
> va2 <- c(2,1,4,2,6,0,3)
> ifelse( 1<va2 & va2<3, 1, 0)
[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

From helpfile (see `?"&"`) you can find the following:

```
& and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter
form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic 
operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first 
element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined.
The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically 
preferred in if clauses.
```